# In what situation would it prove to be more useful to use a hash instead of an array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I'm am just now learning Ruby programming language on my own, and was wondering in what cases would it be more useful to use a hash instead of an array? It seems like a hash is simply an array where each element has a name rather than an index. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really a Ruby question, it's a general data structures question. It's a common question, so Google is probably a better resource than StackOverflow, which leans towards more specific questions. For instance, search "arrays vs hashes" and read through the first few results, there will almost certainly always be something like "why use a hash instead of an array" (actual example at the moment) near the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashes are great as libraries where you want to store specific pieces of information for multiple things. Think of it as an excel table with the columns representing specific data (i.e. Name, Age, Address, etc), and each row represents a single person with specific information stored.

Lets say you want to access a specific information in this hash you built or generated. Well, their name has to be "Philip" and their Age has to be greater than 20.

```
my_hash.each do |person|
  if person[:name] == "Philip" && person[:age] >= 20
    puts person
  end
end
```

Not particularly Ruby, but JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) uses a hash structure to store a ton of information. Also, when you consume API's, a lot of the data you receive will be in hash notation that you will then need to parse and take needed information from.

Answer (score 0):

You're exactly right, while arrays hold an integer as the key, hashes can store any object as the key. because of this, arrays are more data efficient*, but hashes are more flexible. I'd recommend using whichever you are more comfortable with for now, unless you are very concerned with using as little data as possible.